# Angular Swiper width is keeping increase on resize

Tags: angular, sass, swiper.js

I am currently making a banner on a Angular app, and it's not working correctly. The problem is that the width of child element is keeping increase on resize window.

Here is my code snaps for further information:

```
    <swiper
        [slidesPerView]="3"
        [loop]="true"
        [resizeObserver]="true"
        class="spp-swiper"
    >
        <ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let article of articles">
            <img class="spp-banner" src="{{ article.img }} />
        </ng-template>
    </swiper>
```

I am using scss for style, and following swiper module styles are imported.

```
@import "./../node_modules/swiper/swiper.scss";
@import "./../node_modules/swiper/components/pagination/pagination.scss";
```

Have you ever experienced any this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and the solution was applying flex layout to the parent wrapping element.